# How to use/manipulate return value from nested boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I have two functions:
1. A & DataSource();
2. void DataConsumer( A * );

What I want to achieve: ***Using one statement to assemble them into one functor***.

I have tried:

***1.*** boost::function< void()> func( boost::bind( DataConsumer, & boost::bind( DataSource ) ) );

certainly it didn't work, compiler says it can not convert 'boost::_bi::bind_t ' to 'A *'

***2.*** boost::function< void()> func( boost::bind( DataConsumer, boost::addressof( boost::bind( DataSource ) ) ));

compiler says cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::_bi::bind_t' to 'A &'

Question: **how to use return value from the nested boost::bind ? or if you want to use boost::lambda::bind.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys, I just found the answer, like following:

```
boost::function< void()> func(
        boost::bind( DataConsumer, 
                     boost::bind( boost::addressof< A >, boost::bind< A& >( DataSource ) )
                    )            );
```

The theory should be: since we call DataSource later, we need a functor that uses the return value later as well.

Comment: If you can adjust Consumer to take a reference…